# Bash inline pipe with read behavior

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to make this script not require a loop, by re-piping the splitted current line to the next command ?

```
somefunction | while IFS='_' read -a ENTRY
do
  echo "${ENTRY[0]};${ENTRY[3]}"
done
```

It is possible to make a shorter version of it, example :

```
somefunction | IFS='_' read -a ENTRY | echo "${ENTRY[0]};${ENTRY[3]}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pipe shell state (i.e. variables) like that, but if I understand what you're doing, you can use a more appropriate tool for the job:

```
somefunction | awk -F _ '{print $1 ";" $4}'
```

Comment: Good approach. One remark though: the OP didn't use `read -r`; if it's their informed decision then `awk` may not be more appropriate.